# Переименовывание файлов в bash

Tags: bash, linux

Написать скрипт, который переименует каждый файл в каталоге на 1.mp3,2.mp3,...,7.mp3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
export count=0; for i in `find -type f`; do  mv ${i} `basename ${count}`.mp3;  export count=`expr ${count} + 1`; done
```

1. сделать бэкап данных
2. положить в папку с файлами..
3. помолиться..

Тесты

```
sh-4.1$ touch file{1..10}
sh-4.1$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 file10
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 file3
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 file4
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 file5
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 file6
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 file7
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 file8
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 file9
sh-4.1$ export count=0; for i in `find -type f`; do  mv ${i} `basename ${count}`.mp3;  export count=`expr ${count} + 1`; done
sh-4.1$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 0.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 1.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 2.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 3.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 4.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 5.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 6.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 7.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 8.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 shev DomainUsers 0 Фев 20 12:20 9.mp3
```

Comment: Антон, спасибо большое, к сожалению только завтра смогу запустить скрипт.

Comment: @Anton Shevtsov Интересно, в условиях задачи только один каталог или несколько? Если один, то нафига `find`? Да и экспортировать count незачем.

     count=1     
     for i in *; do
       mv ${i} ${count}.mp3
       count=`expr ${count} + 1`
     done

Comment: @alexlz так оно, но мы ничего не знаем о условиях задачи, поэтому такое дубовое решение, к тому же я писал в одну строку постепенно оформив в файл..

Все верно, и ваше и наше. И еще сто тысяч вариантов, которые напишут потомки после нас..

Comment: Ну засекреченность условий задачи -- характерная черта hashcode.ru

Comment: Забыл проверку, что это файл, а не директория (хотя, в зависимости от ситуации, можно проверять и на писабельность, и на принадлежность, и т.д.)

    count=1     
    for i in *; do
      if [ -f "${i}" ] then
        mv ${i} ${count}.mp3
        count=`expr ${count} + 1`
      fi
    done

`"${i}"`, апосторофы -- на случай пробелов в имени файла