# Программа на android для сохранения фотографий в определённом формате?

Tags: android, photo

Добрый день,
фотографирую на телефон много, потом имею кучу файлов с "циферками".
Есть ли какая-нибудь фото программа, что б можно было задать ей- все фотографии сохраняй в таком-то формате, например
Анатомия_№1_07.12.2015
Где бы я сперва ввёл Тему, к чему относится фото, затем, например автоинкремент номер и дату.

Вроде неплохая идея, только гугл не подсказал. 
Может вы пользовались подобными программами?
Спасибо

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопросы по поиску программ - оффтоп.

Comment: Просто идея в том, что групповое переименование не подойдёт, т.к. в один день я могу фотографировать несколько лекций и быть в разных местах, а переименование даст только дату и номер. Если бы можно перед тем как фотографировать задать-например "мой день рождения 2015" и все фотки были бы с этим префиксом, а потом сменил на другое- и фотки пошли с тем префиксом

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить вам следующую программу. Работает в Linux, OS X, Windows (cygwin), возможно и на Android-телефоне, если у вас есть root-доступ.

```
photo() {
    date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d) # сегодняшняя дата
    prefix="_№"
    n=0;
    for file in *.jpg ; do mv  "${file}" $1$prefix"${n}"$date.jpg; ((n++));  done
}

# использование:
cd path/to/photos # переходим в папку с фото
photo "Анатомия"
```

Пишу с телефона, код не отлаживал, но общая идея должна быть понятна. Часть кода взята отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19468016

Кстати, вот ещё:

- [Переименовывание файлов в bash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/194767/181472)
- [Как изменить названия файлов рекурсивно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/472880/181472)

Comment: А Вы не сталкивались с уже готовыми программами?Просто идея в том, что групповое переименование не подойдёт, т.к. в один день я могу фотографировать несколько лекций и быть в разных местах, а переименование даст только дату и номер. Если бы можно перед тем как фотографировать задать-например "мой день рождения 2015" и все фотки были бы с этим префиксом, а потом сменил на другое- и фотки пошли с тем префиксом

Comment: С уже готовыми возможно и сталкивался, но не помню. Дело в том, что рекомендации ПО — вне тематики этого сайта. Но я вам рекомендую попробовать все-таки групповое переименование. Вы можете отфильтровать файлы по времени создания, и тогда под переименование попадет только нужная группа.